# Generalization of set theoretic image, viewed as a function?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

Given a function $f:A \to B$, we can use image of the function to create $F:\mathcal{P}A \to \mathcal{P}B$, defined as $F(X) = f(X)$. How could one generalize this to category theory with power objects? Given a morphism $g:C \to D$, can we find another morphism $G:\Omega^C \to \Omega^D$, which would be analogous to the set theoretic one given above?

Image is generalized as the smallest subobject of a codomain throught which a function factors. I was thinking about using a subobject classifier and somehow find a morphism that would help me, but I couldn't think of anything to connect $\Omega^C$ and $\Omega^D$ in a meaningful way.

Comment: In a topos, you can just use the internal logic and take the interpretation of $\lambda (f : B^A) (S : \mathcal{P} A) . \{ y : B \mid (\exists x : X) (f(x) = y \land x \in S) \}$ to get a morphism $B^A \times \mathcal{P}A \to \mathcal{P}B$.  (And then, of course, $f : A \to B$ corresponds to a global section of $B^A$.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler I'm aware of that, but I want to look for categories in which I could interpret that, without it being a topos. I'd like some minimal requirements.

Comment: @tses So you’re looking at categories which have finite products and power objects but are not toposes? The only thing you’re missing are equalisers. Are you really so concerned about this case?

Comment: @MarkSaving Do power objects with all finite limits imply the existence of subobject classifier and exponential objects?

Comment: @tses Yes. The subobject classifier is just $P(1)$. For exponential objects, the construction is similar to the construction of function sets in set theory. See a standard text like *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic* for details.

Comment: @MarkSaving Oh, right, it was that simple all along. I completely forgot about that construction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are multiple different generalizations of the image available in category theory. In any category with finite limits and colimits you can define the [regular image and regular coimage](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/image#AsEqualizer); the regular image of a morphism $f : x \to y$ is the equalizer of its [cokernel pair](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cokernel+pair), and dually the regular coimage is the coequalizer of its [kernel pair](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/kernel+pair). These are generalizations of "kernel of the cokernel" and "cokernel of the kernel" respectively to "nonlinear" settings. Every morphism then factors as

$$x \to \text{coim}(f) \to \text{im}(f) \to y$$

where the morphism $x \to \text{coim}(f)$ is a [regular epimorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+epimorphism), the morphism $\text{im}(f) \to y$ is a [regular monomorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+monomorphism), and the morphism $\text{coim}(f) \to f$ is both an epimorphism and a monomorphism. If the ambient category is [balanced](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/balanced+category), meaning that every map which is both epi and mono is an isomorphism, then $\text{coim}(f) \to \text{im}(f)$ is an isomorphism and the regular image and coimage coincide; this happens in particular in any abelian category. But in general this won't be true, and the regular image and coimage capture two genuinely different notions of "image."

Here are two suggestive examples:

1. In the category of commutative rings, if $f : R \to S^{-1} R$ is any localization of rings, then the regular coimage is $R$ but the regular image is $S^{-1} R$.
2. In the category of topological spaces, if $f : X \to Y$ is a continuous function, then the regular coimage is the set-theoretic image topologized with the quotient topology from $X$, while the regular image is the set-theoretic image topologized with the subspace topology from $Y$.

So, generally and loosely speaking, the regular coimage is "the image as seen from the perspective of $X$," while the regular image is "the image as seen from the perspective of $Y$."

One can define more generally an image corresponding to any class of monomorphisms you like, as the smallest monomorphism in that class through which a given morphism factors. But there's no guarantee that such a thing will exist in general, whereas the regular image and coimage always exist and are relatively easy to compute under mild hypotheses.

Comment: The OP seems mostly focused on constructing a generalization of the image of subobjects to create a morphism $\mathcal{P}A \to \mathcal{P}B$.  So, for example, if you have a subobject of $U\times A$, then you can form a morphism $U\times A \to U\times B$, and take the image in this sense to get a subobject of $U \times B$.  The question then becomes: is it generally true that this forms a natural transformation in $U$, and therefore induces a morphism $\mathcal{P}A \to \mathcal{P}B$?

Comment: Oh, but since you've already assumed the existence of finite limits, that together with the existence of power objects is already enough to know we have a topos; and in that case, it's definitely true.

Comment: I'm aware of this distinction between images, however, what I'm looking for is the construction of a function $\mathcal{P}A \to \mathcal{P}B$ induced by a function $A \to B$ using arrows only. The idea I got was using the definition of power object and getting the morphism $id \times \chi_r : B \times \Omega^A \to B \times \Omega^B$, but I need to construct the corresponding subobject $r$ of $B \times \Omega^A$, and I'm stuck on that.